# OS X program to view .xif file

Tags: graphics, file-conversion, scanning, image-processing

I have some old .xif image files from a scanning application (Pagis / Scansoft) that I'd like to view/ convert to PDF. Tried all kinds of viewers - Preview, Xee, Adobe (including Photoshop) with no luck.

Please note, as far as I know, .xif / .xiff has nothing to do with exif for cameras.

http://www.fileinfo.com/extension/xif

Thanks very much,
John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general image opening magic I would try:

- ImageMagick (installed via [brew](http://brew.sh/))
- [GIMP](http://gimp.org)
- [XNView](http://www.xnview.com/) This explicitly lists it as possible: http://www.xnview.com/old/en/formats.html
- [GraphicConverter](http://www.lemkesoft.de/en/start/)

ImageMagick and GIMP are free GNU software. XNView is free too.

GraphicConverter is not free, not too expensive either, but can handle just about any image format to have been near a Mac in the last 20 years or so. It has a free trial.

Comment: Gimp works well. Open, potentially rotate if needed, export as jpg.  XNView and XNConvert did not work. Imagemagick correctly identified the files as Tiff but encountered a lot of errors and did not work. I did not try GraphicConverter.